# How do I "use" a class in a Laravel seeder file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have a Laravel seeder file in which I want to use a `Utils` class that I created. The `Utils` class is located at `app/Classes/Utils.php`, but when I add `use App\Classes\Utils as U;` at the top of my seeder file and try to call static methods in the `Utils` class in the seeder, I get the following error:

> Class 'App\Classes\Utils' not found

What am I doing wrong/missing? Thanks.
I am using Laravel 5.8.16 and PHP 7.3.2.

Comment: Can you show class content?

Comment: There's currently one static function with the following signature: `public static function getCsvData($filePath)`. And I'm trying to call it as follows in the seeder: `U::getCsvData('file-path-here')`.

Comment: Check the namespace of your `Utils` class.

Comment: That's what it was, Alpha. I needed to add `namespace App\Classes;`. Thank you.